# Deep relations, *child* relation depends on *great-grandparent* id - with | load - Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many, belongs-to

I have this DB/Model structure (example):

**Food Category ------------ (id, name)* - *irrelevant

**Foods** ---------------------- (id, food_category_id, name, ...)

**Accessory Groups** --------- (id, name, ...)

*Foods_Accessory Groups - (food_id, acc_group_id)* - *pivot table*

**Accessories**            ---------------- (id, acc_group_id, name, ...)

*Foods_Accessories_Prices - (food_id, accessory_id, **price**)* - *pivot table*

**Models**

- FoodCategory (hasMany: foods)
- Food (hasMany: foodAccessoriesGroup)
- FoodAccessoriesGroup (hasMany: foodAccessory)
- **problematic**: *FoodAccessory (**belongsToMany | belongsTo**: food_prices | food_price ------
  (pivot: [price], table: food_accessory_prices, model: Food)

**Test:**
[image: tables]

```
**foods**
| id       | name |
| -------- | ---- |
| 1        | Pork |
| 2        | Eggs |

**accessory_groups**
| id     | name |
| -------| -----|
| 1      | Sauce|

foods_accessory_groups
| food_id  | accessory_group_id |
| -------- | --------------     |
| 1        | 1                  |
| 2        | 1                  |

**accessories**
| id       | name           | acc_group_id |
| -------- | -------------- | - |
| 1        | Mayo           | 1 |
| 2        | Ketchup        | 1 |

**foods_accessories_prices**
| food_id  | accessory_id   | price |
| -------- | -------------- | -     |
| 1        | 1              | 200   |
| 2        | 1              | 300   |
| 1        | 2              | 250   |
| 2        | 2              | 350   |
```

**Code Example:**

```
// get all food and relations
$foodCategories = FoodCategory::with([
  'foods',
  'foods.accessory_groups',
  'foods.accessory_groups.accessories',
  'foods.accessory_groups.accessories.food_prices' or
  'foods.accessory_groups.accessories.food_price' => function ($query) {
    // how to filter food prices by great-grandparent relation food (by food_id)
    // I know that it can't be done here, but where and how
  }
])->get();
```

Accessory *dynamic price* is depended on Food (great-grandparent relation). **What is best practice and most optimize solution for this problem?** Post-process or Laravel Eloquent has solution without too much trouble

[image]

**food (id = 1, Pork)** -> has foods_accessory_groups(id = 1, Sauce) -> has accessories (mayo and ketchup) where **mayo price is 200**, and ketchup price is 300.

**food (id = 2, Eggs)** - ... - **mayo price is 250**, and ketchup price is 350.

**API response** from example:

[image]

Comment: show us your models and provide example output you want to achieve.

Comment: Let's assume I want this Api response. https://ibb.co/ngBN0c3
what is best practice to connect last pivot to his (deep parent) food

Comment: you cannot call the pivot table in that instance because that pivot is between ```food <-> accessories```, and you are calling a relationship between ```accessories <-> accessoriesgroups```, you can only call it directly if you call the accessories directly from the food model, you need to build the relationship from that pivot table back to the food passing through accesoriesgroups, it could be easier to build a raw query but its better to define the relationship between models

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `whereHas` method to query only `FoodCategory` models that have the relationship with the conditions you specify.

```php
$foodCategories = FoodCategory::query()
    ->with([
        'foods',
        'foods.accessory_groups',
        'foods.accessory_groups.accessories',
        'foods.accessory_groups.accessories.food_prices' or
        'foods.accessory_groups.accessories.food_price' => function ($query) {
            // load only models from that relationship that match the condition(s)
            $query->where(...)
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('foods.accessory_groups.accessories.food_price', function ($query) {
        // get only categories that have a nested relationship with condition(s)
        $query->where(...)
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, but that is not what i looking for. I don't need to filter food categories. I need accessories to load food_price connected with great-grandparent relation foods. 
food (id = 1, Pork) -> has foods_accessory_groups(id = 1) -> has accessories (mayo and ketchup) where mayo price is 200, and ketchup price is 300. 
For food (id = 2, Eggs) - ... - mayo price is 250, and ketchup price is 350.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the `accessories` with prices on your Foods model like this

```
public function accessories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( Accessory::class )->withPivot('price');
}
```

or do the reverse inside your Accessories Model

```
public function foods() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( Food::class )->withPivot('price');
}
```

but since you are not querying the food model directly you need to properly define the relationship for each model up until your `FoodCategory` model

Comment: Tnx for answer. I using it like that, but I don't want to  have Accessory model to have foods, but one food only. Filtered by great-grandparent (deep relation).

with( 'foods.accessory_groups.accessories.food' ) where last *food* is equals to great-grandparent in this relation *foods* (first relation)

Comment: check the ```hasManyThrough``` relationship and call it inside your Accessories model with reference to ```Food``` and ```AccessoriesGroup``` Model. or use third party package to build up your relationship like https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep